# Which is best: draw a diagram or plot a diagram (an engineering type of diagram)?

Tags: word-choice

I am to prepare an essay that explains (attempts to at least) how to generate a time-temperature-transformation diagrams, also known as TTT diagrams.
They look like this:
[image: ttt diagram]

Wikipedia link(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isothermal_transformation_diagram)

I need to choose keywords that describe shortly what the essay is for.

Would rather say "how to **draw** a TTT diagram" or "how to **plot** a TTT diagram"?

Perhaps something else entirely?

Comment: Why not use ***generate*** like you did in your question?  *drawing* should focus on the mechanics of putting ink on paper.  *plotting* focuses on placing points on a graph.

Comment: @Jim I am looking to find the most likely word an English speaker would think of when trying to search for this subject. Is the word **draw** used only when one means made by hand rather than computer generated?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: You might also **construct** the diagram.

Comment: @aristotle85- The real question is what are you planning to cover in your essay. Are you covering how to use some tool (say Matlab) to create something like you show- i.e., how to create a graph, choose the axis ranges, add the labels, add the constant lines, set the line styles, add the annotation boxes, etc.  Or are you describing how to test the various materials and collect the data points for plotting?

Comment: @Jim Actually, all the way from an experiment with samples to using a MATLAB-like tool to do the actual graphing. Perhaps **construct** is the best word since the essay goes all the way.

Comment: I, personally, would use ***generate*** since the essay goes all the way through.  In my mind ***construction*** starts after the data has been gathered.

Comment: @Jim I think I will use generate for the essay title and plot for the keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Draw** suggests how to use your hand to create something on paper, and **plot** specifically refers to a graph rather than a more detailed diagram.

So I would suggest "How to plot a TTT graph" or "How to create a TTT diagram".

Comment: "How to plot a TTT graph" it is then.